# How to change specific non-zero values in an array with values of another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays in which one has zero values and the other one only numbers without zero values. Like so

`array1 = [0,0,0,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

`array2 = [456, 299]`

Now I want to exchange the non-zero numbers of array1 with the ones of array2.

That it ends up being like this:

`array1 = [0,0,0,456,299,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

I tried already this:

```js
let array1 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

let array2 = [456, 299]

let j = 0

for (i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {
  if (array1[i] != 0) {
    array1[i] = array2[j]
    j++
  } else {
    array1[i] = 0
  }
}


console.log(array1)
```

That doesn't work because j is undefined within the loop.

Can anyone help me out? Very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the values and take for a truthy value a shifted value from the other array.

```js
var array1 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    array2 = [456, 299],
    result = array1.map(v => v && array2.shift());

console.log(...result);
```

A non mutating version with a closure over the index.

```js
var array1 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    array2 = [456, 299],
    result = array1.map((i => v => v && array2[i++])(0));

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Like the answer but note that it will mutate array2

Comment: @NinaScholz, you are my official hero today, thank you so much for your time and answers! It works like a charm!!

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the iterator from `array2` and call `next` on it to get each value in turn as you `map` over the other array:

```js
let array1 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let array2 = [456, 299]

let it = array2[Symbol.iterator]()
let res = array1.map(n => n && it.next().value)

console.log(res)
```

If you run out of values in `array2` it will add `undefined`s into the array — it's not clear if that's possible or what the correct behavior should be.

Comment: thank you very much Mark. I tested it and it works fantastically

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `i <= array.length` so your else part keep adding a value at the last of `array1` and you run into `infinite loop`, or you can simply use `i < array1.length`

Just remove the else part you don't need else part here

```js
let array1 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

let array2 = [456, 299]

let j = 0

for (i = 0; i <= array1.length - 1; i++) {
  if (array1[i] != 0) {
    array1[i] = array2[j]
    j++
  }
}


console.log(array1)
```

Comment: thank you CodeManiac!! Very helpful, works great and helped me to understand the error of my code!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use map with a curried IIFE so you don't need to create variables that are only used in the map function outside of the map function.

Works if items not zero of array1 are not larger than the length of array2.

```js
const array1 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
const array2 = [456, 299];

console.log(
  array1.map(
    (index => item =>
      item !== 0 ? array2[index++] : item)(0)
  )
);
```

Non IIFE version:

```js
const array1 = [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
const array2 = [456, 299];
//create an index variable to be used in the map function
let index = 0;
console.log(
  array1.map(item => (item !== 0 ? array2[index++] : item))
);
```